# How to import different branch of a package(based on python) in GitHub to local computer?

Tags: python, github, import, branch, cupy

I have a question about import different branch of a repo on Google Colab.

Autograd(https://github.com/HIPS/autograd) have a cupy-adaptable version which lies in another branch(https://github.com/HIPS/autograd/tree/cupy).I want to import autograd(cupy-friendly version into google colab and used following command:

```
!pip install git+git://github.com/ericmjl/autograd/tree/cupy
```

but it have following errors:

> Collecting git+git://github.com/ericmjl/autograd/tree/cupy
>   Cloning
>   git://github.com/ericmjl/autograd/tree/cupy to /tmp/pip-yoasr9_z-build
>   fatal:
>
> remote error:    ericmjl/autograd/tree/cupy is not a valid
>   repository name
>   Email support@github.com for help
>
> Command "git clone
>   -q git://github.com/ericmjl/autograd/tree/cupy /tmp/pip-yoasr9_z-build" failed with error code 128 in None

Is there anybody who can help me with that? Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work: `pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/autograd.git@cupy`

see [VCS support](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#vcs-support).